# Performace tuning at session level while generating flat files being source as database

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Can any one tell me any performance tuning tips at informatica session level.
Source is database(Teradata) and generating flat files. files will come out with millions of records. So thats why workflow is taking longer and longer time to complete. Any performace tips to make the workflow run faster like partitioning or so, i am not sure what to do?

Thanks,
Teja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you need to identify the bottleneck. If possible, please share the post-session stats that can be found it the session log. It starts with `***** RUN INFO FOR TGT...` message and has info about each thread. I could help here.

Then you can start thinking how to address the issue. Some more testing might also be needed: standard approach is to place a `FALSE` filter in the mapping in a few places (after SQ, before target, before a transformation that is suspected to be the issue). And act accordingly.

Unfortunatelly there is no "make it run fast" checbox. You may experiment with some session properties, especially like allowed memory, commit type and interval or even buffer length. But diagnosing and issue solving should come first.